# How do I recreate this toggle in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to recreate this toggle in CSS/HTML and JavaScript. When closed the toggle shows the title: 'Stap 2 Implementatie in de organisatie' and an icon (circle with a plus in it).
When open, it shows some text, and beneath it a section with downloadable tools, they could be implemented as images next to each other, but it's probably more versatile if it's the icon and text separated.

[image: This is the open toggle, the closed toggle only shows the title of the toggle]

[image]

I've managed to create the title, the text underneath it, I just need help with:

1. Different icon for closed and open toggle
2. Extra green section in toggle
3. How to have 20px border radius on button, but only keep the top left and right border radius when clicked/open. (see extra screenshot)

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #7d206a;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-weight:600;
  font-family:'Dosis';
  border-top-left-radius:20px;
  border-top-right-radius:20px;
}
.icon {
float:right;
}

.header {
color:#45b072;
}
.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #7d206a; 
}
p {
color:#fff;
font-family:'Dosis';
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: #7d206a;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion"><span class="header">Stap 2</span> Implementatie in de organisatie<span class="icon">icon</span></button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: about #3, so in your image only the top left/riight border should have a radius?

Comment: When closed, the whole button/toggle should have a 20px radius, when opened/clicked only the top-left/top-right border should stay, so the panel underneath containing the text is fully shown.

Comment: could you add an image for the closed version? it seems that your code already does it.

Comment: Sure! I've added an example of a closed toggle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it like this, I have explained the changes in comments.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #7d206a;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Dosis';
  border-radius: 20px; /* You can have border-radius on all sides */
}

.accordion.active {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px; /* You can set the border-radius of bottom part to 0 */
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}

.icon {
  float: right;
  height: 30px; /* Define height and width for the icon */
  width: 30px;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vvuj2.png"); /* Image for the closed panel */
}

.active .icon {
  /* Icon for the active panel */
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAR5V.png");
}

.header {
  color: #45b072;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #7d206a;
}

p {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Dosis';
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: #7d206a;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

.green-content { /* Properties for the new content */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); /* Four columns for your content as per image */
  background: #45b072;
  margin: 0 -18px; /* Negative margin so that the parent padding doesn't affect it */
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 18px; /* Same padding as parent */
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion"><span class="header">Stap 2</span> Implementatie in de organisatie<span class="icon"></span></button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <div class="green-content">
    <!-- Extra content added -->
    <div class="column-1">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="column-2">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="column-3">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="column-4">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome solution, how would this solution work, if I would have like 6 of these toggles with different content? Do I give all toggles their own class, and own javascript? Some of the extra toggles (not in the same row) I created work, some (in the same row, but different column) don't.

Comment: You just need to duplicate the HTML part and change the content. It would be better if you can open a new question to avoid confusion :)

Comment: Solved the script issue, but now I noticed two things; on safari there is a weird white line/border between the button and the panel with the content?

Comment: What is the other thing? I see that this issue is in the question itself: https://nimb.ws/XpPoku So kindly use the new question button to post about the two things so that we don't mix this up here :)

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a lot of takes for this opinion but I think you should ditch the `panel.style.dipslay` and use class approach instead. So the gist of it is that you add an open state class to the wrapper and based on that you do stuff. I have set it up a bit for you so you can use the class `accordion-container--is-open` to do stuff with your css when the accordion is open

```js
var accordions = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-container");

accordions.forEach(element => {
  const toggler = element.querySelector('.accordion')
  toggler.addEventListener('click', function() {
    element.classList.toggle('accordion-container--is-open')
  })
})
```

```css
.accordion {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #7d206a;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Dosis';
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}

.icon {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.accordion-container--is-open .icon {
  color: aqua;
}

.header {
  color: #45b072;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #7d206a;
}

p {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Dosis';
}

.panel {
  display: none;
  background-color: #7d206a;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

.panel > * {
  padding: 0 18px;
}

.accordion-container--is-open .panel {
  display: block;
}

.accordion__footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 4rem;
  background-color: lime;
}

.accordion__footer-icon {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<h2>Accordion</h2>

<div class="accordion-container">
  <button class="accordion"><span class="header">Stap 2</span> Implementatie in de organisatie<span class="icon">icon</span></button>

  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    
  <div class="accordion__footer">
    <span class="accordion__footer-icon">1</span>
    <span class="accordion__footer-icon">2</span>
    <span class="accordion__footer-icon">3</span>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a play with this

I use delegation and content. You can change content for background image

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");

container.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("icon")) {
    const button = tgt.closest("button");
    tgt.classList.toggle("open");
    const close = !tgt.classList.contains("open");
    tgt.classList.toggle("close",close);
    const  panel = button.nextElementSibling;
    panel.classList.toggle("hide",!close)
  }
})
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #7d206a;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Dosis';
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}

.icon {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
}

.icon.open::after {
  content: "⭕"
}

.icon.close::after {
  content: "❌"
}

.header {
  color: #45b072;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #7d206a;
}

p {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Dosis';
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: #7d206a;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

.hide { display: none;}
```

```html
<h2>Accordion</h2>
<div id="container">
  <button class="accordion"><span class="header">Stap 2</span> Implementatie in de organisatie<span class="icon open"></span></button>
  <div class="panel hide">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```