# How to give a toggle an open state by pageload, while other toggles remain closed

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

A few weeks ago, I found my answer on here to create a certain toggle in CSS. (see: [How do I recreate this toggle in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66905377/how-do-i-recreate-this-toggle-in-css))

I'm using 6 of these toggles on one page. One of them I want to be opened/have the open status when loading the page the others should remain closed.

How would I change the javascript code I'm using for my toggles, so I can have of the toggles opened by pageload? I'm thinking I need to give a that toggle a certain class, and target that class in the javascript, but can't figure it out.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #7d206a;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Dosis';
  border-radius: 20px; /* You can have border-radius on all sides */
}

.accordion.active {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px; /* You can set the border-radius of bottom part to 0 */
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}

.icon {
  float: right;
  height: 30px; /* Define height and width for the icon */
  width: 30px;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vvuj2.png"); /* Image for the closed panel */
}

.active .icon {
  /* Icon for the active panel */
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAR5V.png");
}

.header {
  color: #45b072;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #7d206a;
}

p {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Dosis';
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: #7d206a;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

.green-content { /* Properties for the new content */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); /* Four columns for your content as per image */
  background: #45b072;
  margin: 0 -18px; /* Negative margin so that the parent padding doesn't affect it */
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 18px; /* Same padding as parent */
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion"><span class="header">Stap 2</span> Implementatie in de organisatie<span class="icon"></span></button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <div class="green-content">
    <!-- Extra content added -->
    <div class="column-1">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="column-2">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="column-3">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="column-4">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve this using a pure CSS approach. Rather than drive the display of the panel using JavaScript, you can use the next sibling selector to set the display property. This reduces your JavaScript click handler code significantly and allows it to be more flexible.

1. When the `.active` class is applied to the button, use the `+` next sibling selector to select the panel and provide a property of `display: block;`.
2. Finally, add the `active` class to the `<button>` and the default state is set.

In this way, you're decoupling the *button* behavior from the *panel* behavior.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    /* EDIT 1: Remove the other lines in here */
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #7d206a;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Dosis';
  border-radius: 20px; /* You can have border-radius on all sides */
}

.accordion.active {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px; /* You can set the border-radius of bottom part to 0 */
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}

.icon {
  float: right;
  height: 30px; /* Define height and width for the icon */
  width: 30px;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vvuj2.png"); /* Image for the closed panel */
}

.active .icon {
  /* Icon for the active panel */
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAR5V.png");
}

/* EDIT 2: Add this CSS snippet to allow the panel to derive it's state from the class of the .accordion. */
.accordion.active + .panel {
    display: block;
}

.header {
  color: #45b072;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #7d206a;
}

p {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Dosis';
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: #7d206a;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

.green-content { /* Properties for the new content */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); /* Four columns for your content as per image */
  background: #45b072;
  margin: 0 -18px; /* Negative margin so that the parent padding doesn't affect it */
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 18px; /* Same padding as parent */
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h2>Default Open Accordion</h2>

<!-- EDIT 3: Add the "active" class to the accordion which you'd like to default open. -->
<button class="accordion active"><span class="header">Stap 2</span> Implementatie in de organisatie<span class="icon"></span></button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <div class="green-content">
    <!-- Extra content added -->
    <div class="column-1">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="column-2">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="column-3">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="column-4">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Default Closed Accordion</h2>

<!-- EDIT 3: Add the "active" class to the accordion which you'd like to default open. -->
<button class="accordion"><span class="header">Stap 2</span> Implementatie in de organisatie<span class="icon"></span></button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <div class="green-content">
    <!-- Extra content added -->
    <div class="column-1">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="column-2">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="column-3">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="column-4">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Side Note:**
I also removed the `transition: 0.4s;` property from the accordion and that prevented the bottom corners from animating slower than the panel opening creating an odd effect.

Comment: Wow, thank you. That is a very smart solution. Never heard of the option Adjacent Sibling Selector. Thanks for introducing something new!

Comment: on Safari there's a strange white border though between accordion/panel. Any idea what is happening there?

Comment: @ECDJ Hmm, not sure but I’ll check it out this morning and provide an update as soon as I know something.

Comment: Ah thanks, yes not sure what is happening.